# Why Fun in Zonal gives the same results for "min","mean","count"?

Tags: r, raster

I have two rasters that I would like to compute a 'zonal mean' and number of samples used to compute the mean.It worked fine with the mean but when I wanted to compute the number of samples ''count'', it gave the same results with 'mean'  .I tried also with '"min"' which gave the same.

```
        Library (raster)
        Library (rasterVis)
      Library (lattic)
    r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
    r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
    r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
    r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
    St=stack(r,r1)
    idx <- seq(as.Date('2008-01-15'), as.Date('2008-1-16'), 'day')
     SISmm <- setZ(St, idx)
   dirLayer <- init(SISmm, v='y')
 z <- zonal(SISmm, dirLayer, FUN='mean', digits=2) ## worked fine
 zc <- zonal(SISmm, dirLayer, FUN='count',na.rm=T, digits=2)## the results are the same as z
 zsd <- zonal(SISmm, dirLayer, FUN='sd',na.rm=T, digits=2)## the results are the same as z
```

Any help please?

Comment: I have ideas about why it might be failing, but you failed to include enough code to load the package that has those various functions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary error is that the argument name is `fun`,  not `FUN` . (in previous versions of the package the argument was `stat` . So much for back-compatibility)

You will have problems with `count`, which is deprecated in favor of `freq`, which requires a `raster`-ish object, but so far as i can tell `zonal` converts the data to `numeric` before passing it to the called function.  Possibly you could do `zonal(SISmm, dirLayer, stat=function(k) freq(as.raster(k))` but I haven't tried that out.

Comment: Well, shame on me for running and old version of rasterraster . I'll get back to you.  ->> `fun` is not the same as `FUN`

Comment: @hyat Figure what out?  The argument name is case-sensitive.

Comment: @hyat  Last chance: where do you think you're getting "count" ? There is no such external function.